# Start the video from specific timestamp in HTML using video tag (for large videos)

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, timestamp

I want to start and end the video from specific location or specific timestamp (for instance 15 sec starting and 20 sec ending). Below is my code which works fine for small video but it don't work for large videos. Can anyone knows how it work with large video ?

```
<video id="myVideo" width="740px" height="665px"></video>

<script>

var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
myVideo.setAttribute('src', '../../static/videos/abc.mp4#t=15,20');

</script>
```

Comment: are your "large" videos optimized for streaming (with the MOOV atom moved to the start)? if not, they have to load the entire video to get the metadata that allows seeking to work as expected. with a small video it can happen fast enough you won't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video")

const bounds = {
 min: duration => 20,
 max: duration => duration - 20
}

let intervalId

function clamp() {
  const min = bounds.min(video.duration)
  const max = bounds.max(video.duration)
  
  if (video.currentTime < min) {
    video.currentTime = min
  }

  if (video.currentTime > max) {
    video.currentTime = max
    video.pause()
  }
}

video.addEventListener("play", event => {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
  intervalId = setInterval(clamp, 100)
})

video.addEventListener("pause", event => {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
})
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    Video not supported.
</video>
```

Comment: yes but this work for large videos ? my code is work for small video but not for large videos.

Comment: Can you think of any reasons why it wouldn't work for large videos?